# Jquery, Full Calendar, weekly agenda

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using the jQuery Full Calendar control to display a student schedule,

I've got it pretty much working how we want, but I want to limit the previous and next buttons to only cover a specified range (the two weeks in question).

Is this possible?

Comment: this is the feature request: http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=158

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no native way to do this, but...

fullcalendar.js has two functions in the /* Date */ section called prev() and next().
When the user clicks on the 'next' button, you could disable it to prevent them from navigating any further. When they click 'prev' you could then re-enable the 'next' button and disable the 'prev' button. This would give the user only 2 weeks to play with.